# What was the speed (avg, min, or max) of ARTEMIS-P1 spacecraft as it orbited L1 and L2

Tags: orbital-mechanics, halo-orbit, lissajous-orbit

If not specifically ARTEMIS-P1, then what is the average speed (or mins and maxs) of a spacecraft orbiting EM L1 and L2 in halo and Lissajous orbits?

Are there varied orbital periods for those points?  If so, what is the minimums and maximums?

I started, but did not complete, Classical Mechanics as an undergraduate, so I will not understand a highly technical answer.

Comment: Relative to the Moon, it will be fairly slow, relative to the Moon in a rotating frame it it might be slightly slower. But the challenge will be to get to the understanding that these orbits are really best described as orbits around the Earth, and so their velocity around the Earth is almost the same as the Moon's velocity around Earth. [What do the green lines represent in this Lagrange Point animation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14337/12102)

Comment: I had forgotten to consider it being as described orbiting the Earth.  I am wondering if an astronaut was in a spacecraft as depicted in the video about the JWST https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyyQqaF4tNY would the vertical component (for lack of a more accurate term) of its orbit appear to be moving faster?

Comment: [What's really going to bake your noodle](https://youtu.be/BHGIGwiMK6c?t=2) are the Lagrange point captures of P1 and P2 shown in the video found at https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/3787

Comment: However, P1 and P2 were only in Earth-Moon Lissajous orbits for a period in late 2010/2011, after capture from Earth orbit. ([Stage 3](http://artemis.ssl.berkeley.edu/orbits.shtml#stage3)) Then at the beginning of [Stage 4](http://artemis.ssl.berkeley.edu/orbits.shtml#stage4) they were transferred to high eccentricity lunar orbits. "In early June 2011 P1 was commanded to insert into lunar orbit by performing a series of periselene burn maneuvers; P2 followed suit shortly after. By July 2011 both P1 and P2 were in stable equatorial, high-eccentricity orbits, of ~100 km x 19,000 km altitude."

Comment: cont. "These are stable, 26 hr period orbits with inter-probe separations 500 km-5RE. One probe is in a retrograde and the other in a pro-grade orbit, such that the precession rates of their line of apsides will walk relative to each other by 15-20 degrees per month; in ~2 years the lines of apsides will cover a full circle, resulting in a wide range of inter-probe vectors relative to the Sun-Earth line and lunar wake crossings from a wide range of altitudes." https://i.stack.imgur.com/TREtk.gif

Comment: @ uhoh that is all tremendous information, thank you.  All these questions I have been asking are for a novel I am writing.  I am wanting an astronaut to be in either a halo or Lissajous orbit, and even though the astronaut would be well aware they are actually orbiting the Earth, I want the astronaut to be thinking about the imagine of orbiting around nothing, L1 or L2.

Comment: I see, so Artemis is just an example, got it. I will write an answer accordingly within  a day. As a rule of thumb, an average halo orbit's period is very roughly half of the period of the two body system where it exists. So typical halo orbits around the Sun-Earth L1 and L2 are five or six months, and around Earth-Moon L1 and L2 are one or two weeks.