# Are circuit diagrams available for the Voyager spacecraft telecommunications systems?

Tags: radio-communication, voyager, electronics, doppler-ranging

I'm particularly curious about the coherent transponder mode where the outgoing transmitted signal is phase-locked to the incoming received signal (prompted by @uhoh's recent [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31458/how-many-solar-system-bodies-have-had-coherent-radio-transponders)). This is a mode that the Voyagers are capable of and can provide exquisitely accurate velocity and ranging information.  This capability has proven invaluable for the Voyagers' studies of the plasma environment and the planetary atmospheres and gravitational fields.

This coherent mode sounds difficult to do with a traditional heterodyne down-conversion receiver because the exact phase/frequency of the local oscillator(s) is unknown.  This can presumably be solved if the local oscillators are themselves locked to the signal as recovered at the intermediate frequency (IF).  But the signal frequency seen at IF will depend on the frequency of the local oscillator.  So I'm puzzled as to how exactly this can work.

But just generally, I would be really fascinated to see these circuit diagrams. They are presumably early 70's technology which is at a time when I was working on microwave links with British Telecoms Research.

[Edit: including some info from @kgutwin who pointed me to an excellent and very relevant [Apollo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8gND82t6G4) by CuriousMarc]

Detailed block diagram of Apollo in coherent transponder mode (captured from CuriousMarc video):
[image: Detailed block diagram of Apollo in coherent transponder mode]

The exact same frequency ratios are used in Voyager and apparently even in ISS. So it's likely Voyager uses exactly the same approach and very similar or even identical electronics to Apollo.

Comment: answerers may find helpful links on the following pages [Frequency responses of Voyager's S-band high gain antenna's feed-horn and receiver front end & IF?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17429/12102) and [What is the bandwidth (in hertz) of the Voyager 2 radio receiver?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48603/12102) and [Are the Voyager probes radio output power scalable?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35998/12102) and [Are the Voyager spacecrafts' X-band TWTAs currently set to high or low transmit power? How often were they changed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36000/12102)

Comment: But I think that all roads above will eventually lead to the same thing: [DESCANSO Design and Performance Summary Series Article 4 Voyager Telecommunications](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/DPSummary/Descanso4--Voyager_new.pdf) which has *ample block diagrams* but might not go down to the individual component level. The rest of the Design and Performance summaries [are listed here](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/DPSummary/summary.html) and on the right are links to other series, including the [DESCANSO Book Series](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/mono.html)

Comment: @uhoh thanks, that's great series (DESCANSO), but no circuits and no explanation of how the coherent mode is achieved. Maybe it's obvious - but not to me.

Comment: I'm not convinced you've read through every volume of every series in the DESCANSO ecosystem already. For a discussion on how Voyager's coherent transponder works does [Chapter 3: Voyager Telecommunications of Volume 13 Deep Space Communications](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series13_chapter.html) shed any light?

Comment: Have you seen CuriousMarc's recent series on the Apollo S-Band communications system? He gives a pretty good description of how they achieve coherent transponder mode using Apollo-era gear. I don't know whether any of it applies to Voyager, though. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-_93BVApb58SXL-BCv4rVHL-8GuC2WGb

Comment: @kgutwin I've just listened to the Apollo Comms Part 3 and left a note of appreciation.  It's really helpful!  Apollo also operated with a ''coherent" transponder mode.  And Apollo, Voyager and, apparently, the ISS all use exactly the same frequency ratio so it's likely very similar electronics.  There is a relatively detailed block diagram that is explained in the video.  The approach is exactly what I imagined - only I didn't believe a bootstrap technique like that could possibly work!  But it is obviously a tried-and-true technique that has stood the test of time and space.

Comment: @uhoh I'd already come across the DESCANSO Chapter 3 article and it was helpful in confirming what you'd already stated, but didn't really shed any light on the implementation.  I looked at some of the other chapters briefly and searched for "coherent" but didn't find anything more.  But there is lots of interesting stuff there!

Comment: definitely not Voyager's, but [here's a different and famous spacecraft's radio circuit diagram](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57803/12102)

Comment: @Uhoh I remember listening to the beeps on BBC news.  A nice simple circuit - I wish I could read Dutch - that article looks very detailed.

Comment: @RogerWood other BBC beeps: [How far to de-tune an orchestra to match the BBC World Service pips (beeps)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/74569/37941)

Comment: @uhoh different beeps, but equally fascinating :-)