# Voyager Earth to Jupiter journey time

Tags: voyager, hohmann-transfer

Voyager 1 was launched on Sept 5, 1977 and encountered Jupiter March 5, 1979, a journey of less than 2 years. 
When I try to calculate the trajectory of the probe I assume a Hohmann transfer from Earth to Jupiter even if I'm not 100% about that (the Internet doesn't have a lot of information on that point).

The thing is, when I compute the theoretical time of flight with the following formula:

$$time = \pi*\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\mu_{sun}}}$$

with $a$ the semi-major axis and $\mu_{sun}$ the standard gravitational parameter

$$a=(149598023+778298361)/2 $$

$$\mu_{sun} = 1.32712428e11$$

I find $time=2.7$ years

But in reality Voyager managed to reach Jupiter in less than 2 years so how is that possible?
I thought about the velocity gained by the probe from the Titan 3E rocket which certainly played a role. 
But how can I integrate this velocity in the time formula?

Comment: Have a look at this image: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1#/media/File:Voyager_1_Scaled_Track_de.svg 
The trajectory to Jupiter was much shorter and faster than a Hohmann transfer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It wasn't a Hohmann transfer. The rocket simply boosted it to a higher velocity from Earth in order to enable a Jupiter flyby that would send the spacecraft to Saturn.

You can get the approximate orbit elements from the [JPL HORIZONS Web-Interface](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), picking a day in the middle of the Earth to Jupiter transit (which by the way was 1.5 years):

[image: horizons inputs]

giving:

```
$$SOE
2443666.500000000 = A.D. 1978-Jun-07 00:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 7.969091448846140E-01 QR= 1.003858168243335E+00 IN= 1.036132511480259E+00
 OM= 3.430028790053406E+02 W = 3.591112970337812E+02 Tp=  2443392.027035175357
 N = 8.974748184533540E-02 MA= 2.463325742763491E+01 TA= 1.257125684251016E+02
 A = 4.942901873513668E+00 AD= 8.881945578784002E+00 PR= 4.011254606791074E+03
$$EOE
```

where:

```
  Symbol meaning [1 au= 149597870.700 km, 1 day= 86400.0 s]:

    JDTDB    Julian Day Number, Barycentric Dynamical Time
      EC     Eccentricity, e                                                   
      QR     Periapsis distance, q (au)                                        
      IN     Inclination w.r.t XY-plane, i (degrees)                           
      OM     Longitude of Ascending Node, OMEGA, (degrees)                     
      W      Argument of Perifocus, w (degrees)                                
      Tp     Time of periapsis (Julian Day Number)                             
      N      Mean motion, n (degrees/day)                                      
      MA     Mean anomaly, M (degrees)                                         
      TA     True anomaly, nu (degrees)                                        
      A      Semi-major axis, a (au)                                           
      AD     Apoapsis distance (au)                                            
      PR     Sidereal orbit period (day)
```

There you can see that $a$ is almost $5\,\mathrm{AU}$ — much more than the $\approx 3\,\mathrm{AU}$ for a Hohmann transfer. If it hadn't flown by Jupiter, the orbit would have had an apoapsis of almost $9\,\mathrm{AU}$.

Comment: @MarkAdler excellent!

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** @MarkAdler's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20930/12102)'s new edit is conclusive. Here is some additional perspective.

---

In short - the orbits were elliptical, but already had a semi-major axis much larger than a Hohmann ellipse to Jupiter. The orbits were carefully aimed *nearly at Jupiter* but slightly behind it as it moved in its orbit.

The close flybys would boost their speeds even more and give them more range. $\Delta v$ from [Voyager 1's flyby of Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1#Flyby_of_Saturn) (after Jupiter's flyby) to tilt it's orbital plane far out of the ecliptic. That allowed it to take valuable data at Jupiter first, then to explore the solar system environment *out of the ecliptic plane* past Jupiter as well. [Voyager 2 used four flyby Maneuvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2), at Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, and Neptune, and used the last one to also move out of the ecliptic plane.

You can see a little 3D map-GIF of their orbits below - originally from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14317/12102). The farthest orbit is that of Pluto, you can see on this scale that Jupiter is relatively close to the Sun.

---

**below:** data for the Sun, planets, Pluto, Voyager 1 and Voyager 2, from January 1, 1969 (a good year to start things) until now. Dots are now. Data is from [NASA JPL Horizons](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi). Reposted from [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14317/12102), where additional details are given.

[image]

**below:** *A diagram of the trajectories that enabled NASA's twin Voyager spacecraft to tour the four gas giant planets and achieve velocity to escape our solar system*. From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Voyager_Path.svg).

[image]