# How does the signal strength from the Voyager probe change with distance?

Tags: radio-communication, voyager

How does the signal strength from the Voyager probe change with distance? Where I can find this data?

Comment: see : [Inverse-square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law)

Comment: The question you aren't asking, but probably should be, is what effect that received power drop has, and how long we can continue to communicate with Voyager, as in this question: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14317/how-well-can-voyager-1-separate-earth-signals-from-solar-noise-these-days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signal strength decreases proportional to the inverse square of the distance.

For double distance the strength is only 25 %. For 10 % more distance 17.36 % less signal.

Comment: Maybe add a graph?